# App won't create a new directory

Tags: java, android, file-io

I'm making an audio recorder app. The app is supposed to record files and save them in External Storage Directory. This is how I am trying to do it:

Declaring a few global variables:

```
String externalStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
String outputPath = externalStoragePath + "/Android/data/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad/no_name.mp3"; //output path for mp3 files
File appDirectory = new File(externalStoragePath + "/Android/data/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad"); //this is the directory I want to create when app is started for the first time
```

Few logs in onCreate to check if externalStorage is alright and working as it should be:

```
Log.i("TAG", "External storage directory: " + externalStoragePath);
Log.i("TAG", "External storage state: " + Environment.getExternalStorageState());
```

Log says the External Storage is completely fine (storage/emulated/0) and the state is Mounted.

Then I try to create the directory if it doesn't exist yet:

```
if (!appDirectory.exists())
    {
        try {
            appDirectory.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I know that external storage isn't working as it should if the device is connected to PC by USB cable, so I remove the device from USB and run the app, but the folder isn't created as it should be. Nothing happens basically.

Comment: use appDirectory.mkdir() instead of appDirectory.createNewFile() try and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use mkdir() instead of createNewFile() :

```
 appDirectory.mkdir();
```

Also need to set permission in your AndroidManifest.xml :

```
 android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your Android Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code using which i created a directory:

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myFoler");
        if(!(dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory())){
            dir.mkdir();
        }
```

And dont forget the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in `Manifest` file